# ECS Service can't obtain configuration from Cognito

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

I have a .NET application which has AddAuthentication() and UseAuthentication() for my application. Users are authenticated using Cognito.

```
  services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.MapInboundClaims = false;
                options.Authority = _config.Cognito.Authority;
                options.MetadataAddress = _config.Cognito.Metadata;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    RoleClaimType = "cognito:groups",
                    NameClaimType = "username",
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    RequireExpirationTime = false
                };
            });
```

When I run my application from a local machine and attach to cognito user pool, then it works like a charm.

As soon as I try to connect to the same application by DNS name deployed in ECS, I always face the following issue:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
```

All ipv4 addresses are whitelisted for 80 and 433 ports in my ALB. Would be amazing to get the direction how to deal with the issue.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: ECS cluster is placed in default VPC and a public subnets with routes to IGW. In the same cluster, I have few scheduled tasks that are able to call external APIs without any issues.

Comment: Does your VPC have an internet gateway? is DNS resolution enabled in the VPC? Is the container running your application have an IAM role that permits connectivity to the cognito user pool?

Comment: Hello @AllanChua. I have updated my post with some details. Looks like, that network setup is okay.

Answer (score 1):

> All ipv4 addresses are whitelisted for 80 and 433 ports in my ALB.

That error is completely unrelated to your ALB. Your server is trying to connect to that URL to download the OpenID configuration data. The server is initiating a connection to that URL, which does not involve the load balancer at all. Load balancers are only involved with incoming connections and their responses, not outgoing connections.

Since that URL exists outside of the VPC, the ECS task needs to be configured in one of the two following ways, in order to give it network access to resources outside of the VPC:

- Have public IP address enabled, and be deployed in a public VPC subnet (a subnet with a route to an Internet Gateway)
- Be deployed in a private VPC subnet with a route to a NAT Gateway (the NAT Gateway would need to be in a public subnet)

Comment: Yep, finally realised that I have forgotten to add NAT gateway to send public out of VPC. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Mark. I have checked and can confirm that a cluster is placed in public subnet. Thanks!

Comment: If it is in a public subnet, then you need to enable public IP on the ECS tasks. If it is in a private subnet then you need the NAT Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the issue has been solved. As soon as update the network type from AWS_VPC to BRIDGE, my ECS service started to send and receive traffic from the internet. Many thanks to Mark for heading me to the right direction.